# Unable to build in Gitbash (Windows x32))

Tags: git, build, git-bash

I followed this link https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Build-Instructions
And I am stuck at: **Open a terminal/console/command prompt, change to the directory where you cloned Processing, and type:**

```
cd build
ant run
```

When I type `cd build`, it shows the message

```
bash: cd: build: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: This means that the folder doesn't have a directory named "build".

Comment: I installed JRE 8, apache ant, cloned processing.git. What else do I need to do to make it work. @BilboBaggins

Comment: Did you set up ANT_HOME, JAVA_HOME? etc

Comment: yes I did @BilboBaggins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in a folder, say `C:\Users\myLogin` (replace '`myLogin`' by your Windows account), typing:

```
git clone https://github.com/processing/processing.git
```

That means you then have to `cd processing` in order to be in "the directory where you cloned Processing".

That would be `C:\Users\myLogin\processing` (or, in a git bash, `/c/Users/myLogin/processing`)

Once in that folder, you can type `cd build` and `ant run`.